# Is there a way to reverse flatten a directory? Python or shell?

Tags: python, linux, directory, active-directory, filesystems

Is it possible to do a reverse flatten on a directory?

Current Structure:

```
/dir1
    /dir2
        /dir3
            /main_dir
            |
            --- subdir1
            |
            --- subdir2
                |
                -----file1.txt
```

Target Structure:

```
/main_dir
      |
      --- subdir1
      |
      --- subdir2
         |     
         -----file1.txt
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any flattening there but a migration of the path so may be the move command might work, `mv <old_path> <new_path>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move the directory to another path like so

```
mv /dir1/dir2/dir3/main_dir /
```

this move the `main_dir` to the `/` path

Python:

```
import shutil
shutil.move('/dir1/dir2/dir3/main_dir', '/main_dir')
```